# How to set screen transaction timeout

Tags: moqui

I am doing some development inside a long running screen transaction and it is timing out with: 
--- 1761034  [-task-scheduler] WARN           bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction
 transaction timed out: a Bitronix Transaction with GTRID [3132372E302E302E31000000000EE89002000002A5], status=MARKED_ROLLBACK, 1 resource(s) enlisted

The process keeps running, but it seems to be rolling back a database create action though I don't see a rollback message anywhere. I am not using a service call anywhere.

I thought I would try to lengthen the transition time out value, but I don't see how to do it. It is a screen transaction that is timing out, right?

I will be moving the code to a service, but won't I still have the same timeout problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the screen.@begin-transaction attribute is set to false and no transaction is begun when rendering the screen. On a screen transition element the begin-transaction attribute defaults to true, as those are normally used to process input.

If the logic is in a service you'll have more control over timeouts. Services are where the heavy-lifting is meant to be done. The transactions in screens are just meant for basic transaction needs.